# Whats this LOGON window ? Using VBSCRIPT to send an email message

Tags: email, authentication, vbscript, exchange-server, cdo.message

Image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKvVv.jpg

When I use the following script to connect to an exchange mail server to send my email message I am prompted by the above login window asking for domain credentials. How do I automate my script so I dont get that login window. The workstation sending the email isnt joined to an AD domain.

```
Function sendMail(a,b,c)
set objMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
With objFlds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "email server name"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = a
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = b
    .Update
End With

strBody = "Script has finished running, 6005 is finished"

With objMsg
    Set .Configuration = objConf
    .To = c
    .From = c
    .Subject = "[AUTO] Script has finished running!"
    .TextBody = strBody
    .Fields.update
    .Send
End With
```

End Function

```
sendMail "username","password","my email address"
```

Thanks

John

Comment: It's not clear from this info why it's prompting. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With the line

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 2
```

you are requesting NTLM authentication. This probably causes the login dialog to be displayed.

Please try this instead:

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
```

This causes the `sendusername` and `sendpassword` fields to be used, with "basic authentication". Please note that some email servers are configured to reject "basic authentication".

Comment: Because of how the server is configured I have to use NTLM